# Jetpack Compose: Center only one element in Row

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to align only one Text element horizontally in a Row, the other element should just follow the first one. How can I do this? 
[image]

In the picture, I want the "22" to be centred and the degree symbol to just come afterwards.

I tried something like this:

```
Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center

                ) {

                    Text(
                        "22",
                        fontStyle = androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle.Italic,
                        fontSize = 150.sp,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                    )


                    Text(
                        text = Typography.degree.toString(),
                        fontSize = 150.sp,
                    )
                }
```

and other versions with `weight`, however they did not work. I also tried to wrap it inside a Column with
`horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally`
still no luck. Any idea?

Comment: You need not do that. you can us superscript      `val superscript = SpanStyle(
            baselineShift = BaselineShift.Superscript,
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            color = Color.Red
        )
        Text(
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            text = buildAnnotatedString {
                append("22")
                withStyle(superscript) {
                    append("2")
                }
            }
        )` with just the text itself

Comment: You can use ```ConstraineLayout``` for Compose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in a comment, you can use a [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/constraintlayout) to achieve this.

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1"
```

With a `ConstraintLayout`, you can place elements relative to each other or relative to the parent Composable. So you would use one contraint to center the `22` Composable horizontally, and then use the other constraint to place the `°` Composable to the right of it.

The code could look like this:

```
ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth().wrapContentHeight()
) {

    val (numberText, degreeText) = createRefs()

    Text(
        text = "22",
        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(numberText) {
            centerHorizontallyTo(parent)
        }
    )

    Text(
        text = "°",
        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(degreeText) {
            start.linkTo(numberText.end) // put left of degree to right of number
        }
    )
}
```

The words `start` and `end` refer to `left` and `right` in LTR languages. Besides that, you can also use the keywords `top` and `bottom`.